# Get value of $MYVIMRC from Lua

Tags: neovim, variables, vimscript-lua

I am trying to retrieve the value of $MYVIMRC in my `init.lua` but I am coming up short because I don't understand what $MYVIMRC actually is.

It is not a global variable, is it?

None of these work:

```lua
vim.g.$MYVIMRC
vim.g.MYVIMRC
vim.g.myvimrc
```

What is $MYVIMRC and how can I access it from Lua?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$MYVIMRC` is an [environment variable](http://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-env) that Vim adds to the current environment.

Environment variables are usually inherited by child processes from their parent process. For example, you can see `$MYVIMRC` in a shell that is a child process of Vim:

```
:!printenv | grep MYVIMRC
```

(I use this form rather than just `:!echo "$MYVIMRC"` to "prove" that the value is not inserted before the command is sent to the shell.)

I don't use lua in Vim but I know you can examine environment variables with `os.getenv()` so, for instance, this will print the expected value:

```
:lua print(os.getenv("MYVIMRC"))
```

In other words, you don't need any special Vim API to get the value.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide both the explanation and the Lua code! The $ should have been a clue that it's an environment variable that is simply available in vim.

Answer (score 11):

This is already answered but I just wanted to add another way to access environment variables in lua using vim API.

```
vim.env.whatever -- will give you the value of whatever
vim.env.test = "test msg" -- sets env variable test to value "test msg"
```

I believe this way is more readable and more pleasant to script than using `os.getenv`